# how to import python module inside IDE

Tags: python, import, ide

I have this line of import in my python code:

```
from project.lib.framework.test_cases import TestCase
```

and it works fine when I run it from command line. However, if I try to run it from my IDE (Active state komodo), I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named project.lib.framework.test_case.
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Because you changed the import statement?

In the first example, you are importing from `project.lib.framework.test_cases`, but in the second, you appear to be importing from `project.lib.framework.test_case`. Notice the missing `s` at the end.

Other then that, assuming you are using the same python binary, there should be no difference between an IDE and a command line for `import` statements.